# Action must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async function. React Native

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-redux, expo

I call **getLocalToken** action from my component which reads a string from *AsyncStorage* . The following is how I call the function.

```
componentWillMount() {
            this.props.getLocalToken();
            console.log("CWM", this.props.auth);
        }
```

The following is my Action

```
export const getLocalToken = async () => {
    try {
        const localToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@auth:localToken');
        const mobileNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@auth:mobileNumber');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Failed to read token', e);
    }



    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("get token");
        dispatch({
            type: types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_SUCCESS,
            payload: { localToken: this.localToken, mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber }
        });
    }
}
```

For this code I get **Action must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async function.**  error.

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-descriptive, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out as I am new to Javascript and React Native

Comment: To rephrase the error message, default actions don't support async operations. You will need to use custom middleware if you want to make your actions async, a commonly used option is [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Answer (score 2):

[Actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type property that indicates the type of action being performed. Types should typically be defined as string constants. Please read redux-documentation for more information.

If you want an async request or other side effects you must use `middleware`. Most popular are:

- [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)
- [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)
- [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable)

All of them handle async requests in a different way. `Redux-thunk` is beginner friendly but in my opinion pain for complicated projects and testing.